# KeystoneJS with pug template, variables not displaying properly

Tags: pug, keystonejs

I am reading a book on KeystoneJS and following along with the project. They are using Swig, the project I am supporting uses pug.

I don't know how to get the variables of the models to resolve.

Here is my ticketlist.pug

[Rendered Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBeOR.png)

```
extends ../../layouts/default.pug

block content

  .container
    .panel.panel-primary
  .panel-heading Tickets
  .panel-body
    p
      |These are a list of tickets in the system.

  table.table.table-striped
    for ticket in locals.data.tickets 
      tr
        td
          .col-md-1
            span.label.label-info.pull-right ticket.status
          a.bold(href="ticket.url") ticket.title | capitalize
          ul.ticket-meta
            li &nbsp;
            li
              small Status
              a(href="", rel="tag") ticket.status
            li
              small Priority
              a(href="", rel="tag") ticket.priority
            li
              small Category
              a(href="", rel="tag") ticket.category
            li
              small Last Updated
              abbr.last-updated
              a(href="", rel="tag") ticket._.updatedAt.format('Do MMMM YYYY')
  .panel-footer
```

And here is the view ticketlist.js file from the views

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {
  var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
  var locals =res.locals;

  //used to set the currently selected item in nav heading
  locals.section = 'tickets';

  locals.data = {
    tickets: [],
  };

  //Load all tickets
  view.on('init', function (next) {
    var q = keystone.list('Ticket').model.find();

    q.exec(function(err,results){
      locals.data.tickets = results;
      next(err);
    });
  });
  view.render('tickets/ticketlist');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you either have to use `#{ticket.priority}` or `a(href="", rel="tag")=ticket.category`